# Storm > Howto Integrate Java callback into a Spout

Tags: clojure, streaming, message-queue, apache-storm

I'm trying to integrate Storm ([see here](https://github.com/nathanmarz/storm/wiki/Clojure-DSL)) into my project. I grok the concepts of topologies, spouts, and bolts. But now, I'm trying to figure out the actual implementation of a few things.

**A)** I have a polyglot environment with Java and Clojure. My Java code is a callback class with methods firing streaming data. The event data pushed to those methods, is what I want to use as a spout.

So the first question is how to connect the data coming into those methods, to a spout ? I'm trying to **i)** pass an *backtype.storm.topology.IRichSpout* , then **ii)** pass a *backtype.storm.spout.SpoutOutputCollector* ([see here](https://github.com/nathanmarz/storm/blob/master/src/jvm/backtype/storm/spout/SpoutOutputCollector.java)) to that spout's ***open*** function ([see here](https://github.com/nathanmarz/storm/blob/master/src/jvm/backtype/storm/spout/ISpout.java#L40)). But I can't see a way to actually pass in any kind of map or list.

**B)** The rest of my project is all Clojure. There will be a lot of data coming through those methods. Each event will have an ID of between 1 and 100. In Clojure, I'll want to split data coming from the spout, into different threads of execution. Those, I think, will be the bolts.

How can I set up a Clojure bolt to take event data from the spout, then break-off a thread based on the ID of the incoming event ?

Thanks in advance
Tim

**[EDIT 1]**

I've actually gotten past this problem. I ended up **1)** implementing my own IRichSpout. I then **2)** connected that spout's internal tuple to the incoming stream data in my java callback class. I'm not sure if this is idiomatic. But it compiles and runs without error. However, **3)** I don't see the incoming stream data (definitely there), coming through the ***printstuff*** bolt.

In order to ensure that the event data gets propagated, is there something specific I have to do in the spout or bolt implementation or topology definition? Thanks.

```
      ;; tie Java callbacks to a Spout that I created
      (.setSpout java-callback ibspout)

      (storm/defbolt printstuff ["word"] [tuple collector]
        (println (str "printstuff --> tuple["tuple"] > collector["collector"]"))
      )
      (storm/topology
       { "1" (storm/spout-spec ibspout)
       }
       { "3" (storm/bolt-spec  { "1" :shuffle }
                               printstuff
             )
       })
```

**[EDIT 2]**

On the advice of SO member [Ankur](https://stackoverflow.com/users/553209/ankur), I'm rejigging my topology. After I've created my Java callback, I pass it's tuple to the below IBSpout, using `(.setTuple ibspout (.getTuple java-callback))`. I don't pass the entire Java callback object, because I get a NotSerializable error. Everything compiles and runs without error. But again, there's no data coming to my ***printstuff*** bolt. Hmmm.

```
    public class IBSpout implements IRichSpout {

      /**
       * Storm spout stuff
       */
      private SpoutOutputCollector _collector;

      private List _tuple = new ArrayList();
      public void setTuple(List tuple) { _tuple = tuple; }
      public List getTuple() { return _tuple; }

      /**
       * Storm ISpout interface functions
       */
      public void open(Map conf, TopologyContext context, SpoutOutputCollector collector) {
        _collector = collector;
      }
      public void close() {}
      public void activate() {}
      public void deactivate() {}
      public void nextTuple() {
        _collector.emit(_tuple);
      }
      public void ack(Object msgId) {}
      public void fail(Object msgId) {}


      public void declareOutputFields(OutputFieldsDeclarer declarer) {}
      public java.util.Map  getComponentConfiguration() { return new HashMap(); }

    }
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems that you are passing the spout to your callback class which seems to a bit weird. When a topology is executed storm will periodically calls the spouts `nextTuple` method, hence what you need to do is pass the java callback to your custom spout implementation so that when storm calls your spout, the spout calls the java callback to get the next set of tuples to be fed into the topology.

The key concept to understand is that Spouts **pulls** data when requested by storm, you **don't push** data to spouts. Your callback cannot call spout to push data to it, rather your spout should pull data (from some java method or any memory buffer) when your spout's `nextTuple` method is called.

Comment: Oh nice. Thanks for the insight. But I'm still not seeing the data come through the spout, to my bolt. I've given a better description abouve. Maybe I should be doing something specific with my Spout? Is there a particular way that the data structure has to be passed to the Spout? Thanks.

Comment: @Nutritioustim Did you get an answer?

Comment: Heyya. See abouve. I couldn't get storm to do what I wanted. And ***[Lamina](https://github.com/ztellman/lamina)*** was a much lighter-weight tool that solved my problem. HTH.

Answer (score 0):

Answer to part B:

The straightforward answer sounds to me like you are looking for a field grouping so you can control what works gets grouped together during execution by ID.

That said, I'm not confident that this is really a full answer because I don't know why you are trying to do it this way. If you just want a balanced workload, a shuffle grouping is a better choice.

Comment: Hey, thanks for looking at this. I actually did specify a **:shuffle** to balance the workload. The problem I'm having now, is that I'm not seeing my event data propagate to my bolt (see abouve edit). Any insight there, is appreciated.

Comment: @Nutritioustim did you actually figure out what was the problem?

Comment: @Vor, No. Storm seems a little too unworkable for what I'm trying to do. For now ***[Lamina](https://github.com/ztellman/lamina)*** fills my needs. HTH.